# Free shift swapping software

Tags: gratis, open-source

At my workplace, it is quite easy to give away shifts, but very difficult to swap them. Does any software exist that employees could manage without requiring an overhaul of the current roster software?

Comment: Which operating system(s)?

Comment: It would be best if it could be self hosted on linux, or an online service.